# What's going on with this rather peculiar JavaScript syntax

Tags: javascript

The following JavaScript code:

```
alert(2 .x);
```

Alerts 'undefined' (See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Rp4wk/)

(Note: The space between the '2' and '.x' is intended)

Simple question: Why? Especially when the following yield syntax errors:

```
alert(2.x);
alert(2. x);
```

Anyone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `.` is an operator.  The `2` is a number.  The `x` is (treated as) a property name.

A floating-point numeric constant must not have embedded spaces. Thus, `2 .x` is an expression calling for the constant `2` to be promoted to a Number object, and then the property called "x" is examined. There isn't one, of course, so the value is `undefined`.

You can get the same effect a little more explicitly with

```
alert((2).x);
```

Note that

```
alert("Hello".x);
```

is somewhat similar: in that case, it's not a numeric constant, it's a **string** constant. It's less peculiar because there's no syntactic funny business involved, but otherwise the interpreter does similar things when evaluating. The string constant is first converted to a String object, and then the "x" property is fetched.

*edit* — to clarify a little, `2.x` is an error because it's parsed as a numeric constant ("2.") followed by the identifier "x", and that's a syntax error; two values placed next to each other like that with no intervening operator do not form any sort of construct in the language.

Comment: Holy assignment Batman. Well spotted. This proves it: `Number.prototype.x="Hello there"; alert(2 .x);`

Comment: So, by logical extension `alert(2 .valueOf());` will alert "2"! Hehe!

Comment: But this does not: `Number.prototype.x='bla'; alert(2[x]);`

Comment: `alert(2..valueOf());` or `alert(2..toString());` would also work. @Pointy: nice answer.

Comment: But @mplungjan you forgot the quotes around "x" in that - or try just like the example in the OP, "2 .x" or "(2).x".

Comment: Oops... For fun try this: `Number.prototype.x="bla"; for (var o in 2) alert(o+':'+2[o]);`